# Some questions on ensemble of single-fermion systems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, fermions, second-quantization

> **Example 3.9** (from [Introduction to Many-Body Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521864887))
>
> (a) Enumerate the energy eigenstates of a single fermion Hamiltonian
>   $H = Ec^{\dagger} c$
>
> (b) Calculate the number of fermions at temperature T.
>
> **Solution**
>
> (a) The states are: $|0>$ and $|1>$ with energies $E_0 = 0, E_1 = E$.
>
> (b) The number of fermions at temperature $T$ is given by
>
> $$ <\hat{n}> = \operatorname{Tr} [\hat{\rho} \hat{n}], $$ where
>   $\hat{n} = c^{\dagger}c$,
>
> $$ \rho = e^{-\beta (\hat{H} - \mu \hat{N})}/Z   $$ is the density
>   matrix, and
>
> $$ Z = \operatorname{Tr}[e^{-\beta (\hat{H} - \mu \hat{N})}] $$
>
> is the partition function. And then he writes operators explicitly as
>   matrices for this example:
>
> $$ e^{-\beta (\hat{H} - \mu \hat{N})} =
> > \operatorname{diag}(1,e^{-\beta ({H} - \mu )}),  \hat{n} =
> > \operatorname{diag}(0,1)... $$

from which the Fermi-dirac function for $<\hat{n}>$ comes straightforward.

To my shame I found out I don't understand some things:

- it would make sense if $\hat{n} \equiv \hat{N}$ though in text it is not mentioned. Is it?
- if $\hat{n}$ is a matrix then $c^{\dagger}$ is a matrix (or a vector) itself, but if $|0>$ and $|1>$ are wavefunctions from Fock space how can

$$
|1> = c^{\dagger} |0>
$$ 
this equation hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - it would make sense if $\hat n \equiv \hat N$ though in text it is not mentioned. Is it?

Yes, in this particular case, since we're talking about a one-state system. But in general there could be many states and fermions in a system, and $n_k$ represents the occupation number operator at state $k$th and $N$ is the total number of fermion operator.

> - if n̂  is a matrix then c† is a matrix (or a vector) itself, but if |0> and |1> are wavefunctions from Fock space how can 
>     $$|1> = c^{\dagger} |0>$$
>     this equation hold?

In general, $n$ and $c^\dagger$ are just operators and $|0>$ and $|1>$ are just states. They can be represented in many ways. Using matrices and vectors is just one of the ways to represent them. For instance, we can use
$ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{array} } \right]$ 
to represent $n$ and 
$ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{array} } \right]$ 
to represent $c^\dagger$, from here we have vectors
$ \left[ {\begin{array}{c}  0 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} } \right] $ and 
$ \left[ {\begin{array}{c}  1 \\ 0 \\ \end{array} } \right] $ to represent $|0>$ and $|1>$, respectively. But note that these matrices and vectors are not unique!